# Visual Studio 2022 Community gone crash what should i do?

Tags: error-handling, crash, visual-studio-2022

my Visual Studio reacts like this and when i open properties so it restart automatically

[image]

[image]

I have used Visual Studio 2022 Community for 3 months but suddenly Visual Studio crash as shown in the screenshot and also shows the error

> The program '[11392] API.exe' has exited with code 4294967295
> (0xffffffff).

when I run the project. I tried also to update and repair it to solve this, but the still issue persists.

Comment: Have you added any extensions? Anyway if I were you I would completely uninstall VS, then go through the registry scrubbing it from any leftovers. After that try and reinstall as Administrator.

Comment: No, I didn't add any extensions, I was working last night every thing was normal but when start VS 2022 next day, so it behaves like this, and one more thing it rises error when I run project